# Typescript: Typescript loop showing undefined

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, typescript

```
public Update() {

         this.Data = this.Items;
         console.log(this.Data);
         for (let value of this.Data) {
             console.log(value);
         }
     }
```

console

```
[Object, Object, Object]

Object
CandidateName:"B"
ControlId:0
CreatedBy:null
CreationDateTime:null
ExamId1:2000
ExamName:" Safety"
Id:1292353
```

after last object it showing length:3

when i going to loop over this object,it is throwing error length is undefined,please help me.

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: Do you want to iterate over array of objects or a single object in the array?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect iterate over every single object in that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for in` or `for of` statement should be avoided for iterating over arrays. It has two "drawbacks":

1) The order is not guarantee

2) Also inherited properties will be listed/enumerated, if enumerable:false is not specified when defining the property.

If for example you add a property to your prototype, this loop will iterate also over that one.

```
Array.prototype.test = "test";
var a = ['a', 'b'];
for (let i in a) {
  console.log(a[i]);
}
for (let i of a) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

You should see also your property printed.

If you change your loop into a sequential for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.Data.length; i++ value of this.Data) {
  console.log(this.Data[i]);
}
```

or a:

```
this.Data.forEach((el) => {
  console.log(el);
});
```

you may not see your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `this.Items` is probably undefined in some cases and you cannot iterate.

So:

```
for (let value of (this.Data || [])) {
```

This guards against bad values

Comment: this.Items contain that object arrayand length,length is total number of object.

Comment: this.Data = this.Items in your case, so same thing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over objects, You must use `Object.keys(your_obj)`. Because object doesn't have length property. You can iterate through only of type `'Array'` or `'String'` using `for of`. You can use `Object.keys(your_obj).length` for sequential for loop `for(var i=0; i<Object.keys(your_obj).length; i++)`

```
public Update() {

         this.Data = this.Items;
         console.log(this.Data);
         for (let obj of this.Data) {
             console.log(obj);
             //iterate over object here
             for(let property of Object.keys(obj)){
               // write your logic for specific object
             }
         }
     }
```

Extension to quirimmo's answer, sequential for loop, use this

```
     this.Data.forEach(function(obj){
         console.log(obj);
         //iterate over object here
         for(var i=0; i<Object.keys(obj).length; i++){
           // write your logic for specific object
         }
     })
```

Comment: that means `this.Data` is undefined. So, the problem is somewhere else. What is `this.Items`?